# I think Chrome makes my computer run out of memory

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, google-chrome

Why are there so many "Google Chrome Helper" processes open:

[image]

I have been getting a lot of alerts lately because my mac is out of memory.

I wonder if chrome is the cause, and how I can fix this.

I only had 3 tabs open in chrome when I took the screenshot.

Comment: Chrome is a known memory hog.  You can search on this site and see dozens of questions & answers about that topic.

Comment: In addition to open windows/tabs, every loaded extension has a Google Chrome Helper. Go to the menu Window > Task Manager to see all the 'tasks' Chrome has running.

Comment: I think you'll find every answer will be to stop Chrome from running all the time and limit how many extensions and tabs you have open to only use what you need.  Or, get more RAM.

Comment: @fsb how do I get more ram for my macbook....

Comment: It depends on the MB you have.  I can't answer that but search here for others that upgraded their RAM on your model.  It's not easy or inexpensive but it is an option.  If it was me, I'd just not use Chrome unless necessary.

Comment: "Not using Chrome" is not a very helpful suggestion, BTW.

Comment: Wow. Looking at that screenshot, I'd guess you have 8, 10, or even more tabs open. Try quitting and reopening chrome. Then take a screenshot immediately. How much memory is it using? How many "Google Chrome Helper" processes are open?

Comment: I just quit and reopened chrome. Only one tab open: http://i.cubeupload.com/NB1Jc9.png – doesn't look like as much memory is being used though